# Using join in place of this two seperate queries

Tags: mysql

I have a table by the following structure and records, All i want to do is to just extract list_name of those records whose uid is either 0 or 2 , but i also want to check if a record is available for uid 0 and 2  , then only it should show only record with uid 2... I have managed to do this with two queries... Can i write a single query for this...

```
**id**    **uid**     **list_name**
1            2        favourite list
2            0        Things i love
3            0        my list 
4            2        my lists
5            3        test334
6            2        Things i love
```

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated ..Thanks in advance..

Comment: `but i also want to check if a record is available for uid 0 and 2 ` <- Could you elaborate on this? I don't see duplicates in your example data.

Comment: What should the output look like then? I'm don't quite understand your question, sorry

Comment: Could you maybe show your two-query solution to clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: Perhaps you can write the 2 queries you have and solve your problem?

Comment: ypercube's answer did the work for me.. but thnx to all for your comments and helping gestures...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another guess:

```
SELECT
    uid, list_name
FROM
    myTable T1
WHERE
   uid = 2
   OR
   ( uid = 0 
     AND NOT EXISTS
             ( SELECT * 
               FROM myTable T2 
               WHERE T2.uid = 2
                 AND T2.list_name = T1.list_name
             )
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

A guess...

```
SELECT
    list_name
FROM
    myTable T1
WHERE
   uid IN (0, 2)
   AND
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM myTable T2 WHERE T2.uid = 0)
UNION ALL
SELECT
   list_name
FROM
   myTable T1
WHERE
   uid = 2
   AND
   EXISTS (SELECT * FROM myTable T2 WHERE T2.uid = 0)
```

Comment: thnx , it returned all rows except for rows with uid 0 , which are available only once....